# Weblate glossary doesn't work as expected

Tags: glossary, weblate

I am working on a translation project with Japanese as the source language, using Weblate 4.0. Owner was previously using 3.3, and the same issue was happening. After adding a term into the glossary, it fails to show up when the source string has a match. Japanese does not use spaces between words, so do I need to use regex in the glossary? Seems like a lot of hassle to enter every word and phrase with regex to get a match? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The glossary matching in Weblate needs improvements, there are several related issues on that, see https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/issues/3618 or https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/issues/2183. Feel free to share your input there.

Comment: Thanks. There is not a direct relation to Japanese, but certainly the glossary in general seems to need work. I will post my same question with 3618, because I think it is a bit closer to that issue.